# How to get search result from the original string after searching with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, search-engine

What I've tried here is I can show the file path that contents the string in the `Textbox1.Text` but I cannot get and show the string in that file.

```
private void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\abcdq\Downloads\Documents\", "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
    {
        string settext = GetTextFromPDF(filePaths[i]);
        if (settext.ToUpper().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToUpper()))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(filePaths[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

For example: In the account.pdf, it has:

> New users? For new users, you will need to fill in the form to the
>   right of the page with the following information: Support Reference –
>   This is your support contract number with us e.g. DM1234 or RH1234.
>   Company Name – This needs to be the exact name we know you as to match
>   your support reference. Display Name – Your name, this will
>   automatically be filled in when you use some of the forms in the site.
>   Email & Email confirm – Your email address, this will become your
>   username. Password – A password consisting of at least 6 characters
>   (letters, numbers, and symbols).

1. When I search `email confirm` the result must be return to me the string as `Email confirm` not as `email confirm`.
2. More than that, I am looking for the way to return the string has more some characters in left and right side that string as `Email & Email confirm – Your email address`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know *where* in the string the text you're looking for was found, use `string.IndexOf()`. For example:

```
string searchText = textBox1.Text;
int index = settext.IndexOf(searchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

if (index >= 0)
{
    string foundText = settext.Substring(index, searchText.Length);
}
```

For more complex searches, you can use the `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` class. It returns `Match` objects, which in turn contain `Group` objects that describe the text that was actually matched.

EDIT:

To accommodate returning the context around the found text, use this alternative:

```
string searchText = textBox1.Text;
int prefix = 5, postfix = 5;
int index = settext.IndexOf(searchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

if (index >= 0)
{
    string foundText = settext.Substring(index, searchText.Length);
    int contextStart = Math.Max(0, index - prefix);
    int contextLength = Math.Min(
        settext.Length - contextStart, searchText.Length + prefix + postfix);
    string contextText = settext.Substring(contextStart, contextLength);
}
```

Naturally you can initialize `prefix` and `postfix` however you like; I hard-coded them here just for the sake of the example.

Comment: Because of the large amount of the string, I am still looking for the fastest way of searching. As my survey in the Internet, the Contains() runs faster than IndexOf().

Comment: Well, a) I doubt your "survey in the Internet" actually tells you anything about the _actual_ performance of _your_ code in the real-world, and b) if you need to know what text actually matched, it doesn't really matter whether `Contains()` is faster than `IndexOf()` because the `Contains()` method won't tell you that. Would you rather have code that's fast but doesn't do what you want? Or code that's slower but does do what you want? (Not that you actually have to choose, but if you did...)

Comment: That's great. How to address the case 2 in my thread? In the fist case, your code works very well. However, it now just solves a half of my problem.

Comment: Sorry...the second part of your question wasn't grammatically correct, so I didn't (still don't) understand it. What besides simply subtracting some number from `index` and adding some number to the total length of the substring is it you're trying to do?  That said, it's not a good idea to post two questions in the same post anyway, as it complicates the answering process and runs the risk of answers not noticing the question. IMHO, you should post the second part as a new question, using what you've gotten so far as your starting point.

Comment: Sorry for this inconvenience, my English might not good. So what I would like here is: 5-character + Email confirm + 5-character as `Email & Email confirm – Your`

Comment: Thanks for the details. See edit for second solution.